# Increasing font size based on size of label programatically for a Windows Forms app in C#

Tags: c#, label, autosize, tablelayoutpanel

I want to increase/decrease the font size of the text depending on the size of label in a Windows Forms app using C#.

The label's `Autosize` property is set to `True`. The label is placed on one of the cell of a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Currently I am using the font sizes available in the property of the control to modify the size.

Comment: Autosize = true on winform labels means that the label size will be determined by the size of the text it displays. If you want to determine the side of the text by the size of the label, the first step would be to change Autosize to false.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.